# How to implement a collection that supports real-time filtering?

Tags: data-structures, collections, filtering

I want to implement a mutable sequential collection `FilteredList` that wraps another collection `List` and filters it based on a predicate.

Both the wrapped `List` and the exposed `FilteredList` are mutable and observable, and should be synchronized (so for example, if someone adds an element to `List` that element should appear in the correct position in `FilteredList`, and vice versa).

Elements that don't satisfy the predicate can still be added to `FilteredList`, but they will not be visible (they will still appear in the inner list).

The collections should support:

1. `Insert(index,value)` which inserts an element `value` at position `index`, pushing elements forward.
2. `Remove(index)` which removes the element at position `index`, moving all proceeding elements back.
3. `Update(index, value)`, which updates the element at position `index` to be `value`.

I'm having trouble coming up with a good synchronization mechanism.

I don't have any strict complexity bounds, but real world efficiency is important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to avoid synchronization difficulties is to create a data structure that doesn't need them: use a single data structure to present the filtered and unfiltered data.

You should be able to do that with a modified [skip list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skip_list) (actually, an [indexable skip list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skip_list#Indexable_skiplist)), which will give you O(log n) access by index.

What you do is maintain two separate sets of forward pointers for each node, rather than just one set. The one set is for the unfiltered list, as in the normal skip list, and the other set is for the filtered list.

Adding to or removing from the list is the same for the filtered and unfiltered lists. That is, you find the node at index by following the appropriate filtered or unfiltered links, and then add or remove the node, updating both sets of link pointers.

This should be more efficient than a standard sequential list, because insertion and removal don't incur the cost of moving items up or down to make a hole or fill a gap; it's all done with references.

It takes a little more space per node, though. On average, skip list requires two extra references per node. Since you're building what is in effect two skip lists in one, expect your nodes to require, on average, four extra references per node.

### Edit after comment

If, as you say, you don't control `List`, then you still maintain this dual skip list that I described. But the data stored in the skip list is just the index into `List`. You said that `List` is observable, so you get notification of all insert and delete operations, so you should be able to maintain an index by reacting to all notifications.

When somebody wants to operate on `FilteredList`, you use the filtered index links to find the `List` index of the `FilteredList` record the user wanted to affect. Then you pass the request onto `List`, using the translated index. And then you react to the observable notification from `List`.

Basically, you're just maintaining a secondary index into `List`, so that you can translate `FilteredList` indexes into `List` indexes.

Comment: The problem is that I don't have control over `List`. I'd have to synchronize this skip list data structure with the externally-supplied list, and I can't figure out how to do that.

Comment: Thank you. This fulfills my requirements quite nicely, and is amenable to different levels of optimization.